# Show a div when it matches col-md while not show it when its match col-sm

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show certain image when a certain screen size is matched. in this case for bootstrap, I used col-xx-## as my choice. But seems its not really working the way I think should be.

Basic idea, is i want to show a full screen image of one kind while show another one if the screen size become small.

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="col-md-0 col-xs-12" src="img900x525.png">
  <img class="col-md-12 col-xs-0" src="img300x300.png">
</div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start out with the smaller image visible:

```
.col-xs-0 {
  display: inline;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  display: none;
}
```

then, on larger screens, show the larger version instead:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:70em) { 
  .col-xs-0 {
    display: none;
  }

  .col-xs-12 {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

(adjust the min-width to fit your needs)

Comment: I used your solution because yours is so much more flexible and customizable and I want to do perform CSS3 only adjustment. You win this one! :)

Answer (score 13):

Bootstrap supports using the hidden class, but you will need to hide it for all viewports you don't want the image to show.

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="col-xs-12 hidden-md " src="img900x525.png">
  <img class="hidden-xs col-md-12 " src="img300x300.png">
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but I hate to use bootstrap's js. But thank you very much for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Chen , it is kind of bulky, but is not js.

Comment: Woops my bad, its not. Just dig a second look :) For some reason my page was loading and ask for js when I use hidden syntax. But, yea, it works, and its not js. My fault! Still I will not able to achieve the same flexibility. Though really good answer :) thumb up!